# What happens if an object spins faster than light?

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, event-horizon, faster-than-light

Does a star disappears from space time, if it spins faster than light?

Comment: Assuming here that you mean "What happens if the linear speed of particles on the surface of a spinning star is faster than light?", the answer is - that can never happen.

Answer (score 4):

A star can never spin faster than light (i.e. the linear velocity of particles on the surface can never be faster than light), so the question is moot.